# Cannot login into gerrit

Tags: users, http-authentication, gerrit

I have a gerrit setup on my server with http as a authentication method and nginx as server. I've created a admin account which works perfectly fine. I was trying to set up a another account with command

```
ssh -p 29418 admin@host gerrit create-account --group "'someGroup'" --email user@example.com --http-password "'somePassword'" user
```

and everything looked fine but now I'm not able to log into this account. I can find in nginx error log of gerrit site this error:

```
user "user" was not found in "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd"
```

Should I put this password of new user somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This command creates a Gerrit account but it has nothing to do with authentication on Nginx side, I mean Nginx does not know of accounts in Gerrit so it won't let you pass through basic auth.

HTTP authentication in Gerrit means that www-server handles the authentication, Gerrit simply checks `Authorization` header.

You should add an entry for the new user to `/etc/nginx/.htpasswd` to make it work.

Comment: I see, but in that case what is the purpose of this http-password parameter?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I couldn't find any use case for `--http-password`, probably you may use it with some external auth provider or with some gerrit plugin.

Comment: Documentation says `http-password` may be used to authenticate Git over HTTP and REST API: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#auth.gitBasicAuthPolicy